# Apollo Query Works in GraphIQL but Not in Call to graphql()?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollostack

I have an Apollo query that works correctly in localhost:3010/graphiql:

**QUERY**

```
query getIMs($fromID: String!, $toID: String!){
  instant_message(fromID:$fromID, toID: $toID){
    fromID,
    toID,
    msgText
  }
}
```

**QUERY VARIABLES**

```
{
  "fromID": "1",
  "toID": "2"
}
```

Here's my code to run the query via a call to graphql():

```
const GETIMS_QUERY = gql`
query getIMs($fromID: String!, $toID: String!){
  instant_message(fromID:$fromID, toID: $toID){
    fromID,
    toID,
    msgText
  }
}  `;


const CreateIMPageWithDataAndMutations = graphql(GETIMS_QUERY, {
    options({ toID, userID }) {
        return {
            variables: { fromID: `${userID}`, toID: `${toID}`}
        };
    }
})(CreateIMPageWithMutations);
```

The Chrome Network tab shows the expected Request Payload:

> operationName:"getIMs" query: "query getIMs($fromID: String!, $toID:
>   String!) {↵  instant_message(fromID: $fromID, toID: $toID) {↵
>   fromID↵    toID↵    msgText↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵" 
>   variables:{fromID: "DsmkoaYPeAumREsqC", toID: "572bddac4ecbbac0ffe37fdd"}
>   fromID:"DsmkoaYPeAumREsqC" 
>   toID:"572bddac4ecbbac0ffe37fdd"

But the `data` object is coming back with an ApolloError:

> "Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

How can I correct this?

**Update**

Here's a screen shot of the Network tab:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're getting HTML as the response from your server. Make sure your server accepts a JSON string **and** an object for the variables. graphiql sends a JSON string where Apollo sends an object, you're server should handle both scenarios.

Comment: Where is the setting in Apollo Server to correct this?

Comment: If you're using Apollo Server it [should already](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/apollo-server/requests.html) accept strings and objects "Variables can be an object or a JSON-encoded string". Look in the chrome network requests, what's the response from the server?

Comment: In "view source" next to "Response Headers": …I clicked “View Source” next to “Response Headers”:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> vary: Accept-Encoding
> content-encoding: gzip
> date: Mon, 17 Oct 2016 17:14:02 GMT
> connection: keep-alive
> transfer-encoding: chunked

Comment: Not view source. Once you perform the GraphQL Query on your app, look at the **Network** tab in the developer console. You should see a request to your GraphQL endpoint. That will show you the response from the XHR request that Apollo made.

Comment: I've updated the original post with a screen shot of the Network tab for this call to graphql.  Does this show the info you noted?

Comment: I think I've got Apollo running on a different port than graphql() expects. I'll post later when I get more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Marc Greenstock and @neophi, I found the answer.  I had this code setting up Apollo Client:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: '/graphql',
    opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    },
    transportBatching: true,
});
```

This was defining the uri relatively and using the same port (3000) that Meteor is running on.  But the GraphQL server is of course running on a different port, 3010 in my case. This fixed it:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3010/graphql',
    opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    },
    transportBatching: true,
});
```